# How to allow more than one selection in a CheckedComboBoxEdit?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm working with DevExpress controls in my application. I'm using the checkedComboBoxEdit but when I want select two options, i have a invalid value error directly in the control. Someone knows why and how I can solve it?
Thanks! Nice day!

```
private void checkedComboBoxEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
    foreach (int items in checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.GetCheckedValues()) 
        Prueba(checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties); 
} 

public void Prueba(RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit ri) 
{ 
    int cont = ri.Items.Count; 
    for (int i = 0; cont > i; i++) 
    {
        var valor = ri.Items[i].Value; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The control [clearly allows multiple values to be checked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic) - can you show the code you use to check the values, what the values are, and the *exact* error you receive.

Comment: share some code that how are you binding checkedComboBoxEdit with data source  and how are you getting error??

Comment: Are you checking two items using the UI or using Code ? If using code, it seems you're passing an incorrect value. Please show  your code.

Comment: My invalid value error is represented in the UI.     `private void checkedComboBoxEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (int items in checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.GetCheckedValues())
                Prueba(checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties);
        } 
        public void Prueba(RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit ri)
        {
        int cont = ri.Items.Count;
            for (int i = 0; cont > i; i++)
            {
                var valor = ri.Items[i].Value;
            }
        }`

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know how I make this! :(

Comment: I think your problem might be foreach (int items in  ..) Are you sure all your items are ints?  GetCheckedValues() returns List<object>

Comment: You're right! I review it!

Comment: @DaliaGarcía:Provide information about data that you added in the items otherwise all will guess about the problem.

Comment: It´s a List<> and I'm filling it by BindingSource

Comment: As i have checked that your code is typo and will not run in any case.. second thing you assigning this editor in that grid column which does not have data type as string or other which support csv format in value. When i have assigned it in integer type column then it shows such validation message.. It is the grid control which validating value not the combo editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the documentation and consider assigning this control in column of string datatype rather than some numeric column cell. 
From documentation: [CheckedComboBoxEdit Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic)

> The editor's edit value (BaseEdit.EditValue) identifies all the
>   selected options in the dropdown. With the
>   RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.EditValueType property, you can
>   specify whether to form the edit value as a string or a list.

Hope this information help you avoid setting incorrect value in the grid control which showing validation message for the incorrect value after doing the selection. I have modified [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T393272) DX question sample by specifying the data source and behavior is same as expected after assigning a string in integer column.

```
RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit ccb = new RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit();
List<Student> data = new List<Student>();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    data.Add(new Student() {Id=i, Name= $"Student {i}"});
}
ccb.EditValueType = EditValueTypeCollection.CSV; // It is default value
ccb.DataSource = new BindingSource(data, null);
ccb.ValueMember = "Id";
ccb.DisplayMember = "Name";
ccb.AllowMultiSelect = true;
ccb.EditValueChanged += Ccb_EditValueChanged;
//ccb.Buttons.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton());
//ccb.ButtonClick += Ccb_ButtonClick;
//ccb.Popup += Ccb_Popup;
gridView1.Columns["Name"].ColumnEdit = ccb;  // I have changed it from "ID" column to "Name"
```

If you assign it to the ID column then it will then it expect integer value in cell so raise same error as you are getting after doing selection in the editor.